# why c++ accumulate third argument type cause compile failed

Tags: c++

I write following codes in my editor,but it can't be compiled,it alerts:

```
cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> to 'const char*' in assignment|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
//#inclide <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back(string("a"));
    v.push_back(string("b"));
    v.push_back(string("c"));

    string num = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),"");

    std::cout << num;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it can't be compiled,please someone help me.Thanks:)

Comment: Pass it a string instead of `""`. `string num = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),std::string());`

Comment: because "" is not a string but a char array.

Comment: I think the underlying cause of the confusion is that the definition of `std::accumulate` is slightly different from what you might expect "intuitively".

Comment: See this [reference of `std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/). At the line `init = init + *first++;`, `*first++` has type `std::string` but `init` has type `const char*`. The "addition" compiles but not the assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paragraph 26.7.2/1 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> ```
> template <class InputIterator, class T>
> T accumulate(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, T init);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 1 *Effects*: Computes its result by initializing the accumulator acc with the initial value init and then
>   modifies it with `acc = acc + *i` [...] for every iterator `i` in the range
>   `[first,last)` in order.
>
> [...]

String literals have type `const char[]`, decaying to `const char*` when you pass them to functions. Therefore, the initializer you pass to `accumulate()` would be a `const char*`, and `T` would be a `const char*`.

This means `acc` from the expression above will be a `const char*`, and `*i` will be a `string`. Which means the following will not compile:

```
acc = acc + *i;
```

Because `acc + *i` yields a `std::string`, and on the left side of the assignment you have a `const char*`.

As other have suggested, you should do:

```
 string num = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),string());
```

Also, you do not need to do:

```
v.push_back(string("a"));
```

When inserting strings into the vector. This is enough:

```
v.push_back("a");
```

An `std::string` will be implicitly constructed from the string literal `"a"`.

Comment: Wonderful,I totally understand it.

Answer (score 4):

One of the template parameters of [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is the return type, which would be deduced from the third function argument. This is also a type that should be capable of accumulating the values in the input iterator range. In your case, your return type should be `std::string`, but you are passing `""`, which is a `const char[2]`. This is not a type that can be copied and used for an accumulation.

You can fix this by passing an `std::string`:

```
string num = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(), std::string());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `""` as a third argument, explicitly call `std::string()`:

```
string num = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),std::string());
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `std::accumulate` is the same as the type of the third parameter, which is deduced to `const char*` in your case (because you're passing a string literal in).

This means that the function expects to work with `const char*`s internally, but the iterator range contains `std::string`s, so it barfs. That's why you must pass the correct type (`std::string`) in the third argument:

```
string num = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string());
```